# Why is Android not using the 196x196 favicon?

Tags: android, google-chrome, favicon

I have added a 196x196 favicon as usual to a web page here. This favicon is normally used when doing "Add to homescreen" from Google Chrome in Android. This big favicon normally gets added to the homescreen. But not this time. Instead the smaller 32x32 favicon is added to the home screen (and that does not look nice). Is there anyone who can see what is wrong here?

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/848981/psych/bt/me/memory.html
```

The code for adding the favicon is the one I use on other pages (where it works):

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" type="image/png">
```

---

**UPDATE**
I just tested one of the other sites. Actually the 196x196 icon is used (if I delete the link to the 32x32 icon), but it is shown on the home screen as if it was a small icon!

The recommendation to use 196x196 is here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen#supporting

So I guess this is a bug (a regression) in Chrome then. I will report it. ([Bug 397009](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=397509))

Comment: From [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#HTML5_recommendation_for_icons_in_multiple_sizes) (which may not be the best reliable source, but...) *The Google Chrome web browser however, will select the closest matching size from those provided in the HTML headers to create 128×128 pixel application icons when the user chooses the Create application shortcuts... from the "Tools" menu*. May not apply to Android version though.

Comment: @AndrewT. I think this is for Chrome Web store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome developers has now changed their recommendations and fixed the problems. The preferred favicon size for adding to homescreen is now 192x192.

Please see [Issue 397509 - chromium - The 196x196 favicon is not added to Android homescreen correctly](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=397509). (A 196x196 icon will also work now.)

And my favorite icon creating site has changed to provide 192x192 (instead of 196x196)!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, when exposed to several favicon alternatives, [Android Chrome favors the Apple Touch icon](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility). And although [Google says that it will be deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen#icon), I'm quite sure it will be supported for a while:

- [Chrome does not support the `sizes` attribute yet](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112941). This is a bad start, to the least :)
- [Apple Touch icon, although famous, is not as correctly supported as it should be](http://realfavicongenerator.net/blog/apple-touch-icon-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/). It will take a while before the 192x192 PNG icon becomes popular enough so Google can make it is preferred choice.

My advice: [stick to the Apple specs to create a good Apple Touch icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html). It looks good on Android, too.

In case you need it, this [favicon generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) will create everything you need to get the job done: Apple Touch icons and the 192x192 PNG icon (... for the day it becomes the primary choice of Android Chrome). Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.

Comment: Thanks philippe_b, but see my update to the question. Looks like a Chrome bug.

Comment: I really feel like Google is pushing the 196x196 icon ("Hey! Follow my recommendations, not Apple's!!!") but behind the scene nothing happens. Look at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324820 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112941 . They are closely related and weren't updated for months. However, I think posting a bug is a good thing. Please report the URL as a comment when it is done.

Comment: Thanks philippe_b. The favicon generator you link to now provides a 192x192 size icon which is the new recommended size for the homescreen on Android. See my answer here to my own question.

Comment: Thank you @Leo for reporting the discussion about issue 397509. I've just updated my answer. Another promising feature is the new manifest introduced in Android Chrome M39 (already available as a beta) and documented on https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen . Advantage : the ability to "isolate" the Android icon and prevent other platforms from using it.

Comment: Thanks, I have never heard about JSON-based manifests before. I noticed the support for .manifest files is not yet too good, though. So this was the explanation. I have to test it! ;-)